# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CartUpdate::add() in /server/disk_1/websites/makemyrice/index.php on line 21

Tags: php

I received error like this,

> "Call to undefined method CartUpdate::add()"
>   the error showing on line number 21,

the line is here `" $item = $cartU->add(); "`

```
 <?php 
        $num_rows = 0;
        $cartArray = array();
        include"connect.php";
        include"cart_update.php";
        $count=0;
    $variety = $quantity = $bran = "";


    function test_input($data)
            {
                $data= trim($data);
                $data= stripslashes($data);
                $data= htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;   
            }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))     
    { 
        $cartU = new CartUpdate($_POST);
           $item = $cartU->add(); 

    }

    ?>
```

and my cart_update.php page includes this function

```
function add()
    {
        $variety = test_input($_POST["variety"]);  
        $rice_type = test_input($_POST["rice_type"]);
        $quantity = test_input($_POST["quantity"]);
        $bran = test_input($_POST["bran"]);
        $items[]=array($variety,$quantity,$bran,$rice_type);
        $json = json_encode($items);
        setcookie('cards', $json);
        print_r($items);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you have potentially put the function outside of the class.

Comment: the included function is **inside** the class, right?

Comment: In the file cart_update.php, is the add() function within the CartUpdate class?

Comment: @ryan . add() is outside the cart_update class

Comment: @JohnsonAntony You will need to either call the function simply as $item = add(); or put the function inside the class.

Comment: @JohnsonAntony, This is the 2nd object oriented question asked by you today afaik. I think you need to study OOP before you create your classes.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN.. thankyou for your advice.and  i'm a bigginer in this so,.. thnkyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example please:

```
<?php

    /**
     * Write test2.
     * @return void
     */
    function add() {
        echo "test2";
    }

    class Foo {

        /**
         * Write test.
         * @return void
         */
        public function add() {
            echo "test" 
        }

        /**
         * Call add function.
         * @return void
         */
        public function add2() {
            add();
        }

        /**
         * Call Foo::add() function.
         * @return void
         */            
        public function add3() {
            $this->add();
        }

    }

    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->add();  // test
    $foo->add2(); // test2
    $foo->add3(); // test
    add();        // test2
```